# iterate over line gnupllot

Tags: iteration, gnuplot

all,

I have a file that contains "time" in the first column and then bunch of data points in the following columns, and I want to print all of them to the same file and show how each object moves differently in time, but i am not sure how to iterative over such a file, I have search for a long time but to no luck.

Here is an example of some data:

```
0 0.001 0.006
1 0.001 0.090
2 0.005 0.099
3 0.008 0.999
4 0.009 0.100
5 0.010 0.100
```

Expect in my file i have 100 + lines after the time column. This is what i have so far in my gnuplot loop:

```
do for [i=2:99] {
  plot 'data.out' using 1:i w l lt 7 lw 1 }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks all.

Comment: the data column printed incorrectly, should be N columns, where the first column is time, and the rest of the columns are moving objects.

Answer (score 1):

in case you want to have everything in "one plot", you could interchange the order of the `for` loop and the `plot` command:

```
plot for [i=2:99] 'data.out' using 1:i w l lt 7 lw 1
```

In order to determine the number of columns automatically, one might use the `stat` command as in:

```
fName = 'data.out'
stat fName nooutput

N = STATS_columns #number of columns found in file

plot for [i=2:N] fName u 1:i w l lt 7 lw 1
```